# Why is my Windows / WSL using "Very high" power usage for `cron` and `supervisor` services?

Tags: power-management, cron, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, supervisor

I have Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in WSL. I have a [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) app running via WAMP.

If I run `sudo service cron start`, Windows Task Manager shows "Very high" for "Power usage" for "cron".

Similarly, if I also run `sudo service supervisor start`, Windows Task Manager shows "Very high" for "Power usage" for "php7.4" background process, too.

And my PC fan is loudly spinning fast.

[image]

Running `sudo service supervisor stop` and `sudo service cron stop` of course kills the processes, and then my Task Manager is back to normal levels, and my fan quiets down.

**Why is my Windows / WSL needing to use so much power for `cron` and `supervisor` services?** How can I fix this?

I've never had problems with them when using a non-WSL Ubuntu system or when using Homestead Vagrant VirtualBox.

Comment: *"I've never had problems with them when using a non-WSL"* - You may be confused about the purpose and utility of WSL. It's not intended to run services.  It exists for a fairly narrow purpose: to bring bash and command line utilities to Windows.  MS has said that it's not a good idea to use it to run services and it's definitely not intended for a desktop or GUI apps: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl You are using the wrong tool from the toolbox and that's why you're disappointed

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for that helpful comment and link.